# How to click a checkbox which has a dynamically generated id with WebDriver?

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a form which has a checkbox. The checkbox id value changes every time a new form is opened.  I.e. running the WebDriver test a 2nd or 3rd time, the checkbox will have a different id value.

How can I identify the check box and click it using Selenium-Webdriver C#?

The value which keeps changing is 52309. It is dynamically generated.

```
<td>
    <input id="ctl00_uxFormTemplate_uxApplicationControl_uxQuestionControl_52309_1_52309_1_CHKL_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$uxFormTemplate$uxApplicationControl$uxQuestionControl$52309_1$52309_1_CHKL$0">
    <label for="ctl00_uxFormTemplate_uxApplicationControl_uxQuestionControl_52309_1_52309_1_CHKL_0">Frankenstein</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Is there any invariant data you can anchor your selection to? For example, something besides the ID (like the ID of a table, a preceding  H1. etc.) or perhaps the rest of the ID string without the number (is it invariant and unique?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text of label is always "Frankenstein" then you can use next xpath query `//input[@id=(//label[text()='Frankenstein']/@for)]`. It will find input bu its id where id is got from `for` attribute of label.